# How to prove that the empty set is a half-open interval?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Definition:
$I$ is a half-open interval iff there exists $a \leq b \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $I = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a \leq x < b \}$

My attempt:

Fix a particular $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Since the empty set has no elements at all, then there doesn't exist an $x \in \phi$ s.t $a >x>b$ then $\phi$ is a half-open interval by definition.

Is this correct?

Comment: That definition is not written very clearly.  It should say something like "$I$ is a half-open interval iff there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $I = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a \le x < b\}$".  That makes it more clear what your proof has to do: you have to give two specific real numbers, $a$ and $b$, such that the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : a \le x < b\}$ is empty.  Can you think of two numbers that would work?

Comment: $\varnothing = (a,a]$

Comment: @NateEldredge Fix a particular $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Since the empty set has no elements at all, then there doesn't exist an $x∈ϕ$ s.t a>x>b then $ϕ$ is a half-open interval by definition.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this definition? It looks strange to me. I would expect it to also say that $a<b$. (Maybe it's just me, but without this requirement it just doesn't feel right.)

Comment: Yes. You are right. I modified the def

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix any $a\in\Bbb R$, then

$$\emptyset=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\le x<a\}$$